# Multicolored changing text in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, graphics, colors

Id like multicolored changing text, I made a list with all the colors

I have 5 g.drawString(); functions running, each of them should be the next color in the list (one above each other.)

```
private Color[] colors = new Color[12];
```

Then in my constructor:

```
colors[0] = new Color(255, 0, 0);
colors[1] = new Color(255, 127, 0);
colors[2] = new Color(255, 255, 0);
colors[3] = new Color(127, 255, 0);
colors[4] = new Color(0, 255, 0);
colors[5] = new Color(0, 255, 127);
colors[6] = new Color(0, 255, 255);
colors[7] = new Color(0, 127, 255);
colors[8] = new Color(0, 0, 255);
colors[9] = new Color(127, 0, 255);
colors[10] = new Color(255, 0, 255);
colors[11] = new Color(255, 0, 127);
```

How would I make each each letter a different color?

```
Set The Color: g.setColor(Color object); 
Example: g.setColor(colors[5]);

Write Text: g.drawString(String, x, y);
Example: g.drawString("S", 200, 300);
```

So, Id like S to be the color, colors[0], I made a table below:

```
Starting | First | Second | Fifth

S -- 0      11       10       7
N -- 1       0       11       8
A -- 2       1        0       9
K -- 3       2        1      10
E -- 4       3        2      11
```

So it would loop around though each color:

I tried making a function for this, I deleted the code because I'm an idiot -_-

In my main class, I have a game loop that calls the tick and render methods, tick first then render.

I have an enum called STATE which contains menu and game, then the variable gameState of the type state is set to STATE.menu

```
public enum state {
    Menu,
    Game,
}

public state gameState = state.Menu;
```

When gameState is equal to STATE.menu it will call menu.render(g ( <-- The variable im using for Graphics));

Each class has its own render and tick method.
-Tick method, for setting variables etc, if statements, yada yada yada
-Render method, anything to do with drawing pixels

Because the tick method is called every 0.0000000000000000001 seconds, the color changes every 9 millionth of a second and it looks very derpy.

So ill need a timer of some sorts that I can configure with a variable

I want each of the letters to be a different color, one after another in the list
you can refer to the table above if you don't understand but as an example,

```
the letter a should be colors[0]
and then b, colors[1]
and c, colors[2]
```

the colors should alter,

```
so a would be colors[2]
so b would be colors[0]
so c would be colors[1]
```

I've probably been unclear on 1001 things, so please shout at me in the comments ^-^

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Well done so far. What's your question though? This is just a list of what you've done.

Comment: Can you make your question more concise? It looks like there are multiple issues in one question.

Comment: *"Because the tick method is called every 0.0000000000000000001 seconds"* - Wow, you don't like your users...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hey now, 1 quintillionth of a second is a totally reasonable update time :P

Comment: I dont understand the issue?

Comment: Lets say I have a list with the colors: red blue and green, I have 3 lines of text, "hello" - red, "world" - blue and "YAY!" - green, Every second these should move down so hello would be green, world would be red and green, blue, this should repeat, forever.

Comment: you have to wait after each iteration, may be with Thread.wait(delayTime);  within the for/while loop or as you mentioned using [Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and set the speed to 1000ms so after each ActionEvent the Tick is updated to next value.

Comment: I cant wait though as I need to render other things/I need to keep the rest of the class running.

Comment: You can also create a Class extending Thread or implementing Runnable so the loop and Thread.wait() is independent of your main class.

Comment: @Daniel if you don't have epilepsy :P

Comment: Thanks f the help Kami, but I didn't understand a word you just said xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, there are mainly two issues:

- Painting the letters in different colors, cycling through the given array
- Updating the colors (but at a fixed time, not with every "tick")

Cycling through the colors can be achieved by introducing a "colorOffset". You can add this color offset to the *index* that you use to access the color in the array, and take this modulo the array length to obtain a valid array index:

```
int colorOffset = ... // Counted up or down all the time

// The index of the color for the i'th letter
int colorIndex = (i+colorOffset)%colors.length;
if (colorIndex < 0) colorIndex += colors.length;
g.setColor(colors[colorIndex]);
```

The second part, regarding the update: I assume that you have a game loop that is run in an own thread. Then, in `thisTickMethodThatYouHaveBeenTalkingAbout`, you can check the current system time with `System.nanoTime()`, and compute the time that has passed since the last update. If the time is larger than the desired interval, you perform an update, by increasing the `colorOffset` and triggering a `repaint()` (if necessary - you might cover this already with your `render()` method).

[image: Cycling colors]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MulticolorTextAnimation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MulticolorTextAnimationPanel m = new MulticolorTextAnimationPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(m);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    m.thisTickMethodThatYouHaveBeenTalkingAbout();
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        f.setSize(500,200);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class MulticolorTextAnimationPanel extends JPanel
{
    private String string;
    private Color colors[];
    private int colorOffset = 0;
    private long lastUpdateNs = -1;
    private final long updateIntervalMs = 250;

    public MulticolorTextAnimationPanel()
    {
        setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 45));

        string = "I am a string!";

        colors = new Color[12];
        colors[0] = new Color(255, 0, 0);
        colors[1] = new Color(255, 127, 0);
        colors[2] = new Color(255, 255, 0);
        colors[3] = new Color(127, 255, 0);
        colors[4] = new Color(0, 255, 0);
        colors[5] = new Color(0, 255, 127);
        colors[6] = new Color(0, 255, 255);
        colors[7] = new Color(0, 127, 255);
        colors[8] = new Color(0, 0, 255);
        colors[9] = new Color(127, 0, 255);
        colors[10] = new Color(255, 0, 255);
        colors[11] = new Color(255, 0, 127);
    }

    public void thisTickMethodThatYouHaveBeenTalkingAbout()
    {
        long ns = System.nanoTime();
        if (lastUpdateNs < 0)
        {
            lastUpdateNs = ns;
        }
        long passedNs = (ns - lastUpdateNs);
        long passedMs = passedNs / 1000000;
        if (passedMs > updateIntervalMs)
        {
            // Increase or decrease the color offset,
            // depending on whether the colors should
            // cycle forward or backward
            colorOffset--;
            repaint();
            lastUpdateNs = ns;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();

        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = string.charAt(i);
            int colorIndex = (i+colorOffset)%colors.length;
            if (colorIndex < 0)
            {
                colorIndex += colors.length;
            }
            g.setColor(colors[colorIndex]);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(c), x, y);
            x += fontMetrics.charWidth(c); 
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make it go to the right though, not left?

Comment: You basically have to **decrease** the `colorOffset`... and make sure that the index is positive after the modulo operation. (The latter is something that I would have added anyhow, because otherwise, after running for a few years, the offset might overflow....). The code has been updated accordingly.

Comment: OHHHHMAGOD it looks awesome!